# + and - should be having the different precedence in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started with Angular, and I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <p>This is your first angular expression {{1 +- 2}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

running in this code in the browser gives me the o/p:

```
This is your first angular expression -1
```

How come `-` is taking place instead of `+`. In fact I was expecting a error at runtime, but that doesn't.

Even though the expression is changed to :

```
{{1 -+ 2}}
```

results in `-1`.

`+` and `-` aren't having the same precedence?

### Edit:

Given the expression `{{1 -% 2}}` gives me an error:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '2' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [1 -% 2] starting at [2].
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at throwError (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:5913:11)
    at parser (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:5907:5)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:6470:29
    at $interpolate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:4807:27)
    at addTextInterpolateDirective (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:4436:27)
    at collectDirectives (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:3933:11)
    at compileNodes (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:3816:22)
    at compileNodes (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:3824:15)
    at compileNodes (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js:3824:15)
```

This leaves to me the question, how come `+-` or `-+` is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
1 +- 2
```

Is One plus Negative Two. Which is Negative One. It would be better written as `1 + -2`.

This:

```
1 -+ 2
```

Is One minus the result of converting `2` to a Number (which is Two). This is also Negative One. It would be better written as `1 - +2`

This

```
1 -% 2
```

Just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: E.g.: Unary operators have higher precedence than binary operators.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions correctly evaluate to `-1`:

- `1 +- 2` is equal to `(1) + (-2)`
- `1 -+ 2` is equal to `(1) - (+2)`

On the other hand `1 -% 2` is equal to `(1) - (%2)`. This expression throws an exception because there is no unary operator `%` that operates on a number.

Answer (score 0):

The first one `{{1 +- 2}}` becomes `{{1 + (-2)}}`, which in its turn becomes `{{1 - 2}}` and then `{{ -1 }}`.

The second one `{{1 -+ 2}}` is the same as `{{1 - (+2)}}`, which is `{{1 - 2}}`, so again `{{ -1 }}`.

There is no anything special and also there isn't operations' precedence conflict too.